# How to assign either a string or null to a variable TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a variable which either can take string or null, currently i am defining all the type values hardcoded as below

```
  let name : 'Ram' | 'Shyam' | 'Paul' | null = null;
  name = customer.name as 'Ram' | 'Shyam' | 'Paul' | null;
```

Here, the values are hardcoded, how can i make it generic so that it can intake anything old and new both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check this one

```
type MyValue = "A" | "B" | "C"
type Nullable<T>  = T | null

const a: Nullable<MyValue> = null
```

Comment: I like this Nullable approach, surprisingly I have never seen that before.

Comment: Thanks @Zer0 I'm happy to share it for everyone :)

Answer (score 4):

Just declare a custom type

```
type names = 'Ram' | 'Shyam' | 'Paul' | null;

let name: names = null;
```